# Does hypercohomology of the Koszul complex compute sheaf cohomology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, spectral-sequences, sheaf-cohomology

Let $i:X \to \mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth projective variety defined by the vanishing locus of polynomials $(\underline{f}) = (f_1,\ldots,f_k)$ which have degrees $>0$ and are pairwise coprime, meaning $gcd(f_i,f_j) = 1$ for $i \neq j$. Recall that we can compute the sheaf cohomology of $\mathcal{O}_X$ using the pushforward
$$
H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X) = H^i(\mathbb{P}^n,i_*(\mathcal{O}_X))
$$
If $X$ is a complete intersection, then this can be computed using the koszul complex
$$
H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X) =  H^i(\mathbb{P}^n,K_\bullet(\underline{f}))
$$
Does this result extend even to the general case that $X$ is smooth? That is, does
$$
H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X) = \mathbb{H}^i(\mathbb{P}^n, K_\bullet(\underline{f}))
$$

Comment: I suggest that you compute what happens if you take $X$ equal to all of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and then you take $\underline{f}$ to be $(0,\dots,0)$, where the $\text{i}^{\text{th}}$ component is the zero homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d_i)\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$, for whatever degree $d_i$ that you like.

Comment: Sure. I see how that is a problem, but if I restrict to the case of having polynomials of degrees $> 0$, my question still seems interesting.

Comment: The Koszul complex of $(f,f)$ is equivalent to the Koszul complex of $(f,0)$, and that is going to be a tensor product with a complex like the one in my previous comment.  This issue is persistent.

Comment: and non-equal (or maybe even projectively equivalent) polynomials

Comment: Okay, form the Koszul complex of $(f,f^2)$.  Those polynomials are not projectively equivalent, but you have the same problem.

Comment: Hmm, with no common factors then.